# Get last Wordpress Post displayed on homepage?

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I have theme that use function to get latest posts showed on homepage. But for some reason , it showing previous post , instead latest one. This is function code frorm theme:

```
    $number_of_news = 3;
                if( !empty( $theme_options['home_news_count'] ) ) {
                    $number_of_news = intval( $theme_options['home_news_count'] );
                }

                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'posts_per_page' => $number_of_news,
                    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                            'orderby' => 'post_date',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => array('post-format-quote', 'post-format-link', 'post-format-audio'),
                            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
                        )
                    ),
                    'meta_query' => array(
                        'relation' => 'OR',
                        array(
                            'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
                            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
                        ),
                        array(
                            'key' => 'MEDICAL_META_embed_code',
                            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
                        ),
                        array(
                            'key' => 'MEDICAL_META_gallery',
                            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
                        )
                    )
                );

                // The Query
                $blog_query = new WP_Query($args);


                // The Loop
                if ($blog_query->have_posts()) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="row">
                    <?php
                    while ($blog_query->have_posts()) {
                        $blog_query->the_post();
                        global $post;
                        $format = get_post_format($post->ID);
                        if (false === $format) {
                            $format = 'standard';
                        }
                        ?>
```

i searched on google to find how to get latest posted blog post and found [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts) but now sure what to modify on my code to show me last one. Any help?

Comment: Hi there so as far as I can tell this Query will give you 3 or the number set in the "home_news_count" theme option posts from the default "Post" post type ordered by post date excluding post marked in one of those following categories ( 'post-format-quote', 'post-format-link', 'post-format-audio' ) and which have at least one of the following metas ( _thumbnail_id,  MEDICAL_META_gallery, MEDICAL_META_embed_code). So if you have set the theme option to 1 and it's not returning the latest one it probably means that the latest post doesn't have at least of the meta or it set in wrong post format

Comment: Just compared last two posts. Both have the same post format , so issue is probably into meta.

EDIT: Yes you was in right. One of post dont haved set main image for post. That makes sense, when you say `( _thumbnail_id, MEDICAL_META_gallery, MEDICAL_META_embed_code)` Vital part in sollution was `_thumbnail_id` i suppose. Many thanks this was resolved.